# JQuery Issue: Sticky menu shifts to the right when it sticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Every time that the scroll bar reaches the sticky menu it shifts the menu over a few pixels. If you scroll down slowly on [my website](http://travismorenz.com) and watch the menu you can see it.

I'm using the JQuery plugin stickUp to accomplish the sticky menu. I found that the only way I could get the menu to stick to the top without jumping to the left was by putting the "buttons" class inside of another class called "menu" and setting the width of "menu" to 100%. But that just resulted in the tiny little jump you can see now.

```
<body>
<div id="page1">
    <div id="p1content">
        <h id="Name">Travis Morenz</h>
        <p>Testing & Testing</p>
    </div>
    <div class='menu'>
        <div id='buttons'>
            <div><a href="#page1" class="btn">Home</a></div>
            <div><a href="#page2" class="btn">Projects</a></div>
            <div><a href="#" class="btn">About</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <div class='behindmenu'></div>

</div>
```

I tried setting up a [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/travismorenz/L96x51sw/1/) to make it easier to view but the sticky menu doesn't work inside of it.

The code, however, is the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The buttons also overlap 'page2'. Is that intended?

Comment: yes and i also tried with giving position:relative and z-index but not succeed yet..still trying..please give solution for this if you found :)

Comment: It isn't, im not sure why but it seems as though the buttons aren't quite centered.

Comment: @TravisM, please read my offtopic and change your code, it will help :)

Comment: and also use clear:both after using float so there won't any extra white space. like in your button div, use clear:both

Comment: @Leothelion, It seems like the buttons aren't quite centered on the page. I tried changing the margins but that sends it far to one side or another.

Comment: don't give fix margin as i mentioned..use width:80% then margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto and div will be in center of screen even if you will resize you will see this in center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your site, when you scroll down `.menu stuckMenu isStuck` is getting style and got position:fixed and top:0 but you have to add left:0px then div wont move.

just add left:0px to .menu stuckMenu isStuck and it will work. Please let me know if it wont help or for more explanation.

**UPDATED**
When you scroll down then by jquery there is class added to `.menu stuckmenu` and it gives `position:fixed` and top:0 means fixing the div at one place so you should remove the left part too by using left:0 so it will be in center of screen.(top:0 and left:0). I will update the answer as soon as i will get more clarification.

**OFFTOPIC**
Your content of page 2 will hide the button but if you will hover then it will look like bugs so i have a suggestion that in `.menu stuckMenu` class add `background:white` and it will look great..hope it will help. :)

In this id `#p1content` you have used css which is not good..to center this column you should use `margin-left:auto` `margin-right:auto` with width:80% and you column will be responsive also. Never use fix width, its not good practise.

Comment: This worked perfectly, but could you explain why the .menu.stuckMenu.isStuck was moving it to the right?

Answer (score 0):

It gets moved since position gets changed to `position: fixed;` when you scroll down and it then ignores the margin of the body, making its own margin bigger.

CSS

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution also worked as well, I'm going to try and figure out what the heck was causing it though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I might have figured it out. If you remove the ´margin´ on ´body´, this does not happen. When position: fixed; gets applied to the container, it gets more space than before, and margin: 0 auto; makes the margin-left bigger. So: remove the margin on body and you can ignore my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your question why it was moving: It received some additional style.[image] A position left of 8px.

See screenshot.

This plugin seems to change the position from relative to fixed.

Moreover it adds top- and left-properties.